# Unable to update database when GridView update link is clicked - reverts to old value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am try to allow my users to edit certain columns in my GridView. I have certainly looked at a lot of code and tried many of them to no avail. Using debug my values look good, I'm just not updating my database table. Any help on what I am leaving out would be helpful. thanks again.

```
//Course Name, Course Rating or the Course Slope
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}//end method GridView1_RowEditing

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender,GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow currentRow = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex];

    currentCourseName = ((TextBox)currentRow.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;

    //Get the updated value from GridView
    string currentRating = ((TextBox)currentRow.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
    string currentSlope = ((TextBox)currentRow.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
    string currentCourseID = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].Cells[2].Text;


    theCourseID = Int32.Parse(currentCourseID);
    newRating = float.Parse(currentRating);
    newSlope = Int32.Parse(currentSlope);

    using (GolfDatabaseEntities10 myEntities = new GolfDatabaseEntities10())
    {

        Course obj = myEntities.Courses.First(courseSelected => courseSelected.Course_ID == theCourseID);

        //Should set the values in the table Course
        obj.Course_Rating = newRating;
        obj.Course_Slope = newSlope;
        obj.Course_Name = currentCourseName;

        //Save all changes
        myEntities.SaveChanges();

        //leave edit mode
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        if(!IsPostBack)
            GridView1.DataBind();

    }//end using

}//end method GridView1_RowUpdating
```

Comment: When you bind to the GridView on initial load, are you making sure you're not rebinding for every postback?

Comment: why are you binding in the RowEditing event? if you are editing, the table has already been bound

Comment: pleae post your page_load n markup